# Ringtone to ring for few seconds and stop

Tags: android

I have the following code which would give me a ringtone from my activity. I need this ringtone to keep ringing continuously for 30 seconds. As you can observe from the code below, I stop this ringtone on the 30th second using Timer. The issue I have is, instead of ringing continuously for 30 seconds, it rings for once and then stops. Can someone point out the solution for this such that I can have the ringtone for 30 seconds continuous?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    final Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    r.play();
    final Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            r.stop();
            t.cancel();
            finish();
        }
    }, 30000);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the Ringtone and Timer are deleted after the onCreate.

Make the Ringtone and Timer a private member of your Activity.

Comment: I have only one activity and does it make any difference if these variables are private?

Comment: @user1400538: you can also make them public or protected if needed but they need to be a member variable.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code.

```
private Uri notification;
private  final Ringtone r;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.main);
             playRing();

}//end of onCreate

private void playRing(){
    notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    r.play();
    final Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            r.stop();
            t.cancel();
            // I recommend not to put finish() in onCreate() method
            //finish();
        }
    }, 30000);
}
```